# Binder, thickener, emulsifier for parmesan?

Tags: cheese, food-science

I want to make a paste for coating out of parmesan. With softer cheeses that's not so hard, but how do I blend a hard cheese like parmesan into a paste or colloid-like form? Any suggestions most appreciated!

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the part about why you want this out so there won't be any further confusion - firepig, if you feel it's important, feel free to edit back in, but just try to make it clear that you're not asking whether or not it's good for dogs.

Comment: Also, if you want to ask anything specifically about pets, please see http://pets.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Melt hard cheese with a little sodium citrate to make "processed cheese", which is pourable and moldable while hot

You can make sodium citrate by heating the juice of a small lemon (2 to 3 tsp) in the microwave, and then adding one tsp of baking soda, and heating until it stops reacting (bubbling). Then add 1 cup (~100 g) of grated/shaved/powdered cheese and gently heat until is forms smooth paste. Use a little milk if the cheese is too dry

Comment: Awesome! Can you estimate how much juice that is? Hard to say if your small lemons are the same as everyone else's, and I imagine it's not great if you end up with way too much juice or soda. Also, how much cheese will that help you smooth out?

Comment: Edited. Extra lemon juice enhances the cheese flavour. Not a problem if a bit too lemon juice much as you usually need a little extra liquid as well